# VPN no access to LAN

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, pptp, tunnel

I'm having a problem which surfaced yesterday and is preventing VPN access to LAN. I connect to our workplace's LAN through PPTP VPN; Was working until 2 days ago. Server OS is Windows server 2012. 2 things that seems weird and probably related:

- When connected to VPN Default gateway is 0.0.0.0, however gets IP and correct DNS servers.
- When connected to VPN I'm unable to communicate with any host on the network (ping, RDP, etc.). This includes the router, RRAS server itself, or anything else.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
J

Comment: Well, the gateway is wrong.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it ?